# C++ move semantics string

Tags: c++, stdstring, stdmove

I am working on an embedded system and therefore it is not possible to throw exceptions, just to mention it. Therefore my return value will be a struct. I'm not sure if I have to call std::move on std::string. This below is a very reduced, simplified example.

```
// The response struct
struct Response_Param
{
  size_t status;
  std::string value;
};

Response_Param get_value()
{  
  std::string value = "Response value";
  size_t status{0};

  return {status, std::move(value)};
};
```

In the main code

```
Response_Param param_result = get_value();
if (0 == param_result.status) {
  std::string header_val = std::move(param_result.value);
  // do sth with header_val
  // [...]
}
```

Is it superfluous to call `std::move` in both cases? Or do I gain some performance benefits?

[EDIT]
To make it more clearer why I want to use std::string in this example, I add a more elaborated get_value() function. This function should read a http header key-value pair:

```
/**
* @param key [in] The http header key to 
* look for. If found, the lib function 
* will fill up the char* raw ptr by this 
* value.
* @param max_len [in] The max_len of the  
* header value. If header value > max_len 
* returns a truncation status.
**/
Response_Param get_value(const char*key, const size_t max_len = 200)
{  
  std::string value;
  size_t status{0};

  status = get_hdr_key_val_lib(key, value.c_str(), max_len);

  return {status, std::move(value)};
};
```

Comment: How do you cope with the out-of-memory condition? In this line `std::string value = "Response value";`, `std::string` constructor allocates. This can fail. Do you have a plan?

Comment: if possible you'd do `return {0,"Response value"};`. I guess its only simplification of the code that makes this possible, though `"Response value"` is a string literal and maybe you don't need to construct the `std::string` before returning it ?

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. not yet :o, good catch

Comment: yeah it's a simplification because I want to use get_value as a wrapper for  some library function size_t get_val_lib(const char*key, char *val, size_t val_size), which copies the found http header key value to the pointer and returns an error if the header value got truncated. I don't want to dynamically create a char raw pointer in the heap, because I would have to manage the deletion of the char pointer outside of the wrapper function manually. That's why I really would want to use a std::string instead.

Comment: Offtopic: This line under "Edit": `status = get_hdr_key_val_lib(key, value.c_str(), max_len);` doesn't look right. You've forget to resize `value` before and after, C API is used. So you have undefined behavior there.

Comment: @MarekR Interesting. Could you tell me more why a resize is necessary? This is a good hint: I have an idea: First, get the header value length (I have a library function for that) and then call std::string value; value.reserve(hdr_val_len);

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are reinventing `std::optional`?

Comment: @chris As it is now string has no capacity, it's c_str() will point to the internal 14 char buffer for small string optimization. If you write more than 13 chars to it you have a buffer overflow. Without small string optimization it probably points to a global empty string or something things are even worse. If you `reserve` then the string will have the right capacity and writing to it will work. But that won't change the size so at the end your string is still empty as far as the string knows. Also **Writing to the character array accessed through c_str() is undefined behavior.**

Comment: You have to first `value.resize(max_len)` the string to the full length so that the needed buffer is allocated and the string size is set. Then you can use `value.data()` to get the header value. Last `if (status >= 0 && status < max_len) { value.resize(status); value.shrink_to_fit(); }` to get the string down to the actual length of the value. Note: I assume `status` should be `ssize_t` with `-1` as error. And you should return `std::optional<std::string>` or `std::variant<ssize_t, std::string>` aka `std::expected` in C++23.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I would advise to rewrite the function so that [named return value optimization (NRVO)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) kicks in.

```
Response_Param get_value()
{  
  Response_Param result{ 0, "Response value" };

  return result;
}
```

But as you write that you get the value from a wrapped library function and need to copy it, that change does not help you much. So in your case you can get a performance benefit from using `std::move` for the string.

If you want to see the difference, then just run the program in a debugger, step through it and check when copies are made and when moves are made.

BTW, I doubt that your wrapping of `get_hdr_key_val_lib` is correct. You are passing `value.c_str()` as second parameter, but that it a `const char*` pointing to an empty string (as `value` has not been assigned any value). You probably meant to reserve some space first and then to pass `value.data()`?

Comment: get_hdr_key_val_lib: The second argument is a pointer to the buffer into which the value will be copied. This happens internally in the lib function. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it should be enough to pass value.c_str() into the second arg, since this gives me the raw pointer back.

Comment: @Chris https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str "Return value: Pointer to the underlying character storage." but "Writing to the character array accessed through c_str() is undefined behavior.". The return type `const char*` makes it clear already. `c_str()` gives you a pointer to a const buffer.